# Why does this Spark code throw java.io.NotSerializableException

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, serialization, rdd

I want to access a companion object's method inside a transformation on an RDD. Why does the following not work:

```
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
import spark.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql.{Encoder, Encoders}

class Abc {
    def transform(x: RDD[Int]): RDD[Double] = { x.map(Abc.fn) }
}

object Abc {
  def fn(x: Int): Double = { x.toDouble }
}

implicit def abcEncoder: Encoder[Abc] = Encoders.kryo[Abc]

new Abc().transform(sc.parallelize(1 to 10)).collect
```

The above piece of code throws a `java.io.NotSerializableException`:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable
  at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:298)
  at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:288)
  at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:108)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:2094)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$map$1.apply(RDD.scala:370)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$map$1.apply(RDD.scala:369)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:362)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.map(RDD.scala:369)
  at Abc.transform(<console>:19)
  ... 47 elided
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: Abc
Serialization stack:
        - object not serializable (class: Abc, value: Abc@4f598dfb)
        - field (class: Abc$$anonfun$transform$1, name: $outer, type: class Abc)
        - object (class Abc$$anonfun$transform$1, <function1>)
  at org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationDebugger$.improveException(SerializationDebugger.scala:40)
  at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializationStream.writeObject(JavaSerializer.scala:46)
  at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.serialize(JavaSerializer.scala:100)
  at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:295)
  ... 57 more
```

Even defining an `Encoder` for the class Abc doesn't help here. But the more important question is, why is the serialization of an object of class Abc being attempted at all? My first thought was that the companion object is a singleton object of the class, so maybe there's an attempt to serialize it. But doesn't seem like the case, because when I call Abc.fn from another class:

```
class Xyz {
    def transform(x: RDD[Int]): RDD[Double] = { x.map(Abc.fn) }
}

implicit def xyzEncoder: Encoder[Xyz] = Encoders.kryo[Xyz]

new Xyz().transform(sc.parallelize(1 to 10)).collect
```

I get a `java.io.NotSerializableException: Xyz`

Comment: The work doesn't happen on the edge node; the class (or object) has to be serialized so the data nodes can run it.

Comment: Because you did not actually define the serialise/deserialise functions much less even implement the proper Interface? (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/NotSerializableException.html) By default sereilsiation can only access stuff that is both publically set and get-able. For anything beyond that, you need to provide your own functions.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a great article that discusses "serializable" vs. "non-serializable objects in Apache Spark:

[Using Non-Serializable Objects in Apache Spark, Nicola Ferraro](https://www.nicolaferraro.me/2016/02/22/using-non-serializable-objects-in-apache-spark/)

The article offers several suggestions as to:

- What's going on in your particular case
- Some alternatives so your object doesn't need to be "serializable"

Answer (score 2):

The main abstraction os spark is RDD which are partitioned across the node of the cluster. So when we run the RDD, It is serialized in the driver node and it is distributed to other appropriate nodes. Then the worker nodes deserialize it and execute.

In your case, The class ABC cannot be serialized and distributed to other worker nodes.
You need to serialize the Class ABC with Serializable

```
class Abc with Serializable{
    def transform(x: RDD[Int]): RDD[Double] = { x.map(Abc.fn) }
}
```